# Network request in `didEnterBackground` not always received by backend

Tags: ios, swift

I have an issue with `didEnterBackground`. In `viewDidLoad` I have the following code:

```
NotificationCenter
    .default
    .addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(didEnterBackground),
        name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
```

with the function `didEnterBackground`:

```
@objc func didEnterBackground() {
    // I have checked course always has a value and it does
    guard let course = self.focusedCourse.value else { return }

    switch course.status {
    case .finished:
        // I have also debugged to check playTime has a value and it does

        // API call
        Worker.PutLessonProgress(lessonID: course.id, progress: Int(playTime.value)).request(completion: nil)
    case .live, .upcoming, .todayUpcoming, .free:
        break
    }
}
```

My worker class is just a wrapper around `Alamofire`.

When I enter the background via switching (eg my app is open then I switch to app B) the API call is successful 100% of the time. However if I open the app and then immediately force-quit the app (eg don't change to a different app and just swipe the app closed) although `didEnterBackground` is called (checked via logging) it seems that the API request frequently doesn't make it to the server.

Is it normal for `didEnterBackgroundNotification` to be unreliable like this or have I made a mistake in my code somewhere?

Comment: What do you mean by *immediately quit the app*? How are you "quitting"?

Comment: Updated in description

Answer (score 0):

The Notification is not unrelyable. It just not gurantees you execution time. If the user terminates the app, any execution is stopped.

Not sure what your Worker class is doing, but just use a URLBackgroundSession to get your data delivered by the os itself.

Comment: `URLBackgroundSession` won't work since the app isn't in the background. It is terminated.

Comment: Kex, you're correct that background sessions won't work if the app is force-quit by the user (swipe-up), but background sessions generally speaking do not require the app to be in the background. They work even if the app is terminated by the system, just not force-quit. There is no way to continue a transfer if the user force-quits in the way you describe. This is by design.

Comment: It’s force quit I’m looking for, if app is switched to another app and enters background it has plenty of time to do its API call and not an issue. Thanks for spotting this question!